# How to read the properties defined in config server inside the express

Tags: express, configserver

I have config server which is a containerized. now my task to create a API in express. the problem i am facing is how to read the common properties defined in the config server in my express api.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a .env File to store your environment variables. Example: .env.development or .env.test or .env.production files that you can put into a config folder.
2. Download the node module "node-foreman" https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman
3. Now run your web server using foreman and specify which environment you want with the following command line command.

```
./node_modules/foreman/nf.js --env ./config/.env.development start web=1
```

That will load the correct environment that you want.

Then to access your environment variables in the actual code, you use "process.env".

For example if you have a key-value pair in your .env file like **version=5.5** then to access it in the code you do **process.env.version**.